# Problems removing a package

Tags: apt, dependencies, 19.04, dconf

I'm having an issue removing `libdb5.3` from my Ubuntu 19.04 (fresh install).

I upgraded today because I was stuck and unable to update/upgrade anything on 18.04 due to a known issue so I decided it was time to do a fresh install of the latest version.

I need to remove `libdb5.3`, as the software I am compiling needs `libdb4.8` (which comes with for compilation). However, when it detects this version, it puts out a warning because any version higher than 4.8 is not portable database-wise.

When I try to run `sudo apt-get remove libdb5.3`, I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dconf-gsettings-backend : Depends: dconf-service (>= 0.30.1-2)
                           Depends: dconf-service (< 0.30.1-2.1~)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've done the usual

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg -a --configure
```

to no avail. I still can install, upgrade and remove anything I want, except that package, which shows these problems.

Other possibly useful information:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep ^h
```

returns nothing.

`sudo apt-cache policy dconf-gsettings-backend`:

```
dconf-gsettings-backend:
  Installed: 0.30.1-2
  Candidate: 0.30.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 0.30.1-2 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`apt-cache policy dconf-service`:

```
dconf-service:
  Installed: 0.30.1-2
  Candidate: 0.30.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 0.30.1-2 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`apt-cache policy libdb5.3`:

```
libdb5.3:
  Installed: 5.3.28+dfsg1-0.5ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 5.3.28+dfsg1-0.5ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.3.28+dfsg1-0.5ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.3.28+dfsg1-0.5 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
```

I have been looking around for solutions but none has worked.

Comment: Some system packages depend on `libdb5.3` : `apt rdepends libdb5.3` ... You can remove `libdb5.3-dev`, **not libdb5.3**. ... Solution : install year 2012 `libdb4.8, libdb4.8-dev` http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/db4.8/ .... No conflicts, no dependencies !

Comment: Thank you, guess old dogs can learn new tricks. that worked like a charm.